# "in efforts to" vs "in an effort to"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, articles, determiners, zero-article

Is *efforts* being used properly in this sentence because we are promoting multiple efforts?

1. **In efforts** to promote our products, we are providing a website and flyers for your use.

Or should it be:

2. **In an effort** to promote our products, we are providing a website and flyers for your use.

Comment: Is "promoting your products" one effort, or many? Even if you say it's one effort, are you sure you can't conceptually break it down into smaller discrete efforts? Let's just say you make an effort to lose 10 pounds. Isn't it also true that you make repeated efforts every day to lose a small portion of those 10 pounds?

Comment: [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/attempt) gives examples of both 'in an attempt to ...' and 'in attempts to ...'. There is a similar choice here. As Zebrafish says, the choice is yours: do you want to emphasise a concerted though multi-part effort, or the multiple strings of that effort?

Answer (score 1):

The second answer sounds grammatically correct because "providing a website and flyers for your use" is one effort. Had there been multiple efforts being described in the second part of your sentence, you should have used 
"in efforts". 
E.g. "In efforts to win the match, our team hired a foreign coach, and tried to bribe the referee."